# How to split a big .txt file with \n and not \r\n

Tags: script, regex

I want to split a .txt file. First, I opened the .txt file with notepad++ and I changed the EOLs from `\r\n` to `\n`.

Then I wanted to split the file into 10 pieces and for that, I used a tool called split or join and also this script.

When I check I see the EOLs are set back to `\r\n`.

How do I split a .txt file and keep the same EOLs?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\split files"
SET /a fcount=100
SET /a llimit=10000
SET /a lcount=%llimit%
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\list.txt") DO (
CALL :select
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set dfile') DO IF /i "%%b"=="dfile" >>"%%c" ECHO(%%a
)
GOTO :EOF
:select
SET /a lcount+=1
IF %lcount% lss %llimit% GOTO :EOF
SET /a lcount=0
SET /a fcount+=1
SET "dfile=%sourcedir%\file%fcount:~-2%.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: `regex`? Where are the regular expressions?

Comment: Did you get a solution on this already? I quick SED command should fix this right up easily and quickly. I have this stored away somewhere I can find and post an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this DOS2UNIX.  This program will convert your text file so it removes the extra characters that are added when you save it as a Windows program.   Put this program on your system, add it to your PATH and include it in your script after you do your split.  It should remove your extra characters.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/

Comment: i did this http://tinypic.com/r/29dwuf6/9

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is detecting the EOL format when opening the file and saving the file in the same format. To change a given file to UNIX-format EOL (only `\n`), there is a simple menu command:

Edit > EOL Conversion > UNIX/OSX Format

Comment: i did this: http://tinypic.com/r/29dwuf6/9 i replace \r\n  to \n and then i split the same list in 2 parts and as u can see in the 2'nd picture  /n  not anymore, \r\n back again --> http://tinypic.com/r/2nbap08/9 .I need something to split the file and keep the \n space and not back to \r\n\